# HTA redirect - mask URL

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, hta

I'm having trouble redirecting my main website **www.mydomain.com** to the folder **mydomain.com/stuff/public_html/index.html** while retaining **www.mydomain.com** in the URL. I'd  prefer to use HTA over some html solution, but what's the most SE friendly and modern solution for this?

I've tried the simple HTA 301 redirect below, but it shows the file path which I want to avoid.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/stuff\/public_html\/" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the formatting above, I've tried the simple HTA 301 redirect, but it shows the folder path in the URL.

Comment: Add it to the question and mention what issues you're seeing with it. The more detailed the question, the more likely you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: I like the edit. I think the question is more relevant and its easy to figure out what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not need an external redirect. You need an internal redirect. For this you need to remove the [R] flag in your rule (and have only [L]). The [R] flag forces an external redirect with a HTTP 301 response code.

Comment: I changed it to [L] but it still shows the directory path, which I need to hide.